# React Native Image Styling

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

```
I want to set my image according to screen size and 
dimension but I am not able to do it please help me out
```

If I rotate the phone it should set accordingly

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Image source={img1} style={{flex: 1}} />
   </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways you can try to do scaling of your images:

- **resize mode** (https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode)
- **resizemethod** (Android Only)(https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemethod-android)
- **Dimensions & Pixel Ratio** (https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio)

Using Dimensions and Pixel ratio you can set the height and width of the image based on your device.

> Note: You can comment down if you need additional information.